# Fedora Boot Progress Bar

Tags: linux, boot, fedora-12, progress

Can we customize the boot progress bar in fedora 12? If yes, than how to customize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following links provide guide to customize the plymouth which also include boot progress bar.

http://brej.org/blog/?p=158

http://brej.org/blog/?p=174

http://brej.org/blog/?p=197